# A question about an inequality for hafnians of some special matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, inequalities

Let $S$ by a complex symmetric $2m$ by $2m$ matrix. Let $\sigma$ be the $2m$ by $2m$ matrix which is the direct sum of $m$ copies of the following matrix:
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$
We assume that $S \sigma$ is an hermitian positive semidefinite matrix (h.p.s.d. for short).

Is it true that $\Re(\operatorname{haf}(S)) \geq \prod_{i=1}^m s_{2i-1,2i}$, where $\operatorname{haf}$ is the hafnian?

I ran some numerical testing for small values of $m$ and it seems to be true.